# facebook registration plugin - zipcode field from facebook?

Tags: php, python, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

is it possible to add zipcode and address field to the fields in facebook registration. If possible, how can i add them ? They are actually available in our facebook profile so there must be a way we can add them .

```
<iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?
         client_id=appid&
         redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.facebook.com%2Ftools%2Fecho%2F&
         fields=name,birthday,gender,location,email"
    scrolling="auto"
    frameborder="no"
    style="border:none"
    allowTransparency="true"
    width="100%"
    height="330">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is it possible to add zipcode and address field to the fields in facebook registration.

No – at least not to get them pre-filled by Facebook.

FB does not give this information out to apps any more – so if you need it, you’ll have to request it from the user via custom fields, for them to fill out manually.